# Create a separate log4j2 log for each forked java process

Tags: java, log4j2, processbuilder

I would like to have a separate log file created for each process forked by a main process.

In log4j2.xml, a log file name is declared as:

```
fileName="${sys:loggingFileName}.log"
```

In an initial class, say class A, a log is created:

```
public class A {
    System.setProperty ("loggingFileName", "MyLogA");
    log = LogManager.getLogger (A.class);
    ...
    log.info (...);
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder ();
    Map<String, String> environment;
    environment = pb.environment ();
    environment.put ("CLASSPATH", System.getProperty ("java.class.path"));
    pb.command (Arrays.asList ("/usr/bin/java", "class B"));
    final Process process = pb.start ();
}
```

Class B could look exactly as above (with the appropriate substitution of B for A, and C for the creation of the new class).

When started separately (not through ProcessBuilder), Class A and class B each create a separate log as expected.

However, when class B is forked from class A using ProcessBuilder, a MyLogA.log file is created containing the specified log entry, but no MyLogB.log.

I don't understand why.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Additionally: I have tried placing :

```
pb.redirectOutput (Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError (Redirect.INHERIT);
```

or

```
pb.redirectErrorStream (true);
```

prior to the pb.start, with no change.

Comment: When you run it directly, do you pass anything on the command line, in `-D` options?

Comment: No, the processes are designed to start with no parameters, everything coming from the log4j.xml file.

Comment: If you're on Windows, it may be that the CLASSPATH environment variable doesn't affect it. You should pass it with command arguments (`Arrays.asList("/usr/bin/java", "-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path"), "class B"`).

Comment: I'm not on Windows, and I have tried passing the class path both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below lines of code before starting any processbuilder in order to redirect logs to particular log file.

```
Process p = null;

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(......);

File logFile = new File("path to file/nameOfFile");

logFile.createNewFile();
            pb.redirectErrorStream(Boolean.TRUE).redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(logFile));

p = pb.start();
```

This will create a start redirecting all the logs from process to this file as soon as `pb.start` is called.

Comment: That seems to work.  Why is it that the log4j2 streams don't operate the same?